# wordpress 6.2 is alignfull and lignwide removed?

Tags: wordpress, editor

i am using a custom block theme, and i have support for alignwide and full. now i test my theme on 6.2 and the buttons for wide and full are not showing.

in my functions.php file i have this: add_theme_support( 'align-wide' );

and in my theme.json file i have: "layout": { "contentSize": "860px", "wideSize": "1100px" },

so now in the front if i add manually the classes: alignfull or alignwide, it does work. but in the editor (posts, pages and site) i have a group, cover and other blocks, in the align options there are no alignfull or alignwide.

any idea what is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found the issue at least for me, so maybe it will help others: on my templates , on the post-content comment i added: {"layout":{"type":"constrained"}}

that fixed the align issues.